# Linear Algebra (Span, Basis, $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \{(-2,0,1), (5,-2,1), (11,7,-5), (-1,4,-2), (2,-3,1)\}$. Show that Span(*S*)=$\mathbb{R}^3$ but *S* is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find a subset of *S* that is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and prove that your subset is actually a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Hi, thank you in advance for your help.

What I'm currently on:

1) Proving Linear Dependence (since *S* is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$).

2) Proving *S* span $\mathbb{R}^3$

I'm currently stuck proving that this span in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Because when I set (-2,0,1) = k1*v1+k2*v2+k3*v3+k4*v4, I got a 3x4 matrix (I have to proof the determinant is nonzero), and I don't know how to find the determinant of 3x4 Matrix.

3) Can anyone shed a light on how can I find a subset of *S* that is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: $S$ cannot be a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ since it consists of more than three elements (and thus must be linearly dependent). This follows immediately from the definition of dimension of a vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can set up a matrix and find the row echelon form of that matrix to figure out the dimension of the space.
   The row echelon form of the matrix
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   -2 & 0 & 1 \\
   5 & -2 & 1 \\
   11 & 7 & -5\\
   -1 & 4 & 2 \\
   2 & -3 & 1 \\
   \end{array} is
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{array}
   The rank of this matrix is 3, which means the set of vectors span a space of dimension 3, so span(S) = $R^3$
2. A set of vector in a vector space is called a basis if vectors are linearly independent, and every vector in the vector space is a linear combination of this set. However in this case, we can write $<-1,4,2> = 5<-2,0,1>+\frac{1}{3}<5,-2,1>+\frac{2}{3}<11,7,-5>$. Therefore S is not a basis for $R^3$.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your help on this.

I have a question - so to prove that span(S) = R^3, do we only have to do RREF and judge by the nonzero rows or columns?

and is there any way we can find a subset of S that is a basis for R^3?

Thanks a lot once again for your help

Comment: RREF pretty much does the job. If the zero vector can be written in only the trivial way and the number of vectors matches the vector dimension, it forms a basis. (Invertible matrix theorem)